# Unresolved reference after importing?

Tags: python, import, pycharm, python-import, importerror

This is driving me crazy and I feel like I've tried everything. I successfully imported Flask and date yesterday but I came back to the code today and tried installing CORS but it's not working. I've installed the package CORS and I invalidated caches/restarted but it still says that it's an unresolved reference.
[image]

After I invalidated caches/restarted it, it briefly showed no errors until the 'Indexing Python SDK 'Python 3.9 (backend)' bar at the bottom loaded completely and then it showed the import as being unresolved again.

I had done this exact command before to install flask and it worked and now it's not working for CORS:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything between yesterday and today which is why I don't understand this. I looked at similar posts to this and tried their advice but it's not working. Any suggestions I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same interpreter?

Comment: I am running it from the same powershell instance, too. I don't know how anything could have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use PyCharm, setup a Python venv in there and install everything in there using the build in Terminal in PyCharm. Then check if its working. Here is how:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html